# Can arsenic contaminating calcium carbide enter banana skin during artificial ripening?

Tags: food, health, poison

Calcium carbide which is used for ripening banana contains arsenic, is it possible for that arsenic to enter banana skin?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] and ask only one question at a time.  Your second question about the way calcium carbide ripens fruit is quite different from how it enters banana skins. Please edit your question to remove it and pose it as a separate question. That way it will be indexed as such.

Comment: Welcome. Can you add your findings so far? Apparently you did some research, linking the relevant web pages would help, as your findings so far on the permeability of banana skin to arsenic